Manipulate innerText in a slot while keeping slot style with svelte
I want to make a component that makes a typewriter effect, but I need to keep the styling inside the slot so I can use any text style with the same effect.
Main file :
<TypewriterText>
    <h1>Hey what's up!</h1>
</TypewriterText>

TypewriterText.svelte :

<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let content = '';
    let currentText = '';
    let currentIndex = 0;

    onMount(() => {
        const data = document.querySelector('.hidden');
        content = data?.innerText || '';
        typeWriter();
    });

    function typeWriter() {
        if (currentIndex < content.length) {
            currentText += content.charAt(currentIndex);
            currentIndex++;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, 10);
        }
    }
</script>

<span class="hidden"><slot /></span>
{currentText}

<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>


The only way I found is to hide the slot and reproduce the innerText below. But this way I lose the  html tag...
Thx a lot !!

You could put TypewriterText in the h1.

You have to switch h1 and TypewriterText so it applies the styling before the text effect.
<h1>
   <TypewriterText>Hey what's up!</TypewriterText>
</h1>

Also, using an action would be more suited to your need.
<script>
    const typewriter = node => {
        let timeout = undefined;
        const fullText = node.textContent;
        node.textContent = '';
        type();

        function type() {
            if (node.textContent.length >= fullText.length)
                return;

            node.textContent = fullText.substring(0, node.textContent.length + 1);
            timeout = setTimeout(type, 100);
        }

        return { destroy() { clearTimeout(timeout); } }
    }
</script>

<h1 use:typewriter>Hello there</h1>

REPL
